# PowerShell Core: Get cert object from PFX file

Tags: linux, powershell, .net-core

Using PowerShell on Linux, how do I get an [X509Certificate2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2?view=net-6.0) object from a PKCS#12 file (aka PFX file) ?

On Windows, it's done like this:

```powershell
$cert = (Get-PfxData -FilePath "mycert.p12" -Password $secstr).EndEntityCertificates[0]
# Pass cert object to some cmdlet, in this case MS Graph API:
Connect-MgGraph -Certificate $cert .....
```

The problem is that the [PKI module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pki/) is not available for Linux. I tried to dig into the background for all of this mess, and I think it is a consequence of the shortcuts that .NET Core is taking when it claims to be "cross-platform". (hint: it ain't true cross-platform as Microsoft has decided to rely on OS specific libraries for a lot of the security related stuff, unlike for example the route Java is taking). When the background .NET features are not there then consequently it is not possible for Microsoft to create the parity on PowerShell either.

Apart from my rant, can you answer my question? How would I do it?

#### Update (solution)

As per [Toni's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73916937/1504556) this will work on Linux:

```powershell
$cert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2("myfile.p12",$secstr)
```

(not aware that there's any PowerShell binding for this, calling directly into .Net from PowerShell is not my favorite, but it does the job)

The PKCS#12 format allows a file to include an unlimited number of certificates. I'm assuming that the above will only work when the PKCS#12 file only has one certificate (chain) in it or that the behaviour in case of multiple certificate chains is un-specified. But one certificate (chain) is most typically the case. Or at least the case in my scenario.

The above works for me using Linux and PowerShell 7.2. To be certain I've tested with a `.p12` file *not* created by PowerShell.

Comment: You could use OpenSSL. That’s what I use for all my certificate management

Comment: @Fitzgery: How would use you OpenSSL to read from a PKCS12 file into an object of type `X509Certificate2` ? (which is what the question is about)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows if the certificate is stored in the certificate store you can access the cert by using get-childitem, e.g.:

```
$cert = Get-ChildItem  -Path 'Cert:\LocalMachine\MY' | ?{$_.Thumbprint -eq $thumbprint}
```

If the certificate is stored plain on the disk I think its the same for Linux and Windows:

```
#Without Password
$cert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2([path])

#With Password
$cert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2([path],[password])
```

X509Certificate2 Class is part of the .NET Core, so it works on Linux too.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2?view=netcore-3.1

Alternatively you can also use a password as secret to connect to Azure by using a ServicePrincipal, e.g.:

```
$tenandId = #fill the Id of your Tenant here
$clientId = #fill in the Id of the ServicePrincipal here
$secret = #fill in the password of the ServicePrincipal
#HashTable used for splatting
$paramsHt = @{}

$body = @{
    Grant_Type    = 'client_credentials'
    Scope         = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'
    Client_Id     = $ClientID
    Client_Secret = $Secret
}
#Establish connection and obtain Bearer Token
$con = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantid/oauth2/v2.0/token" -Method 'Post' -Body $body
#Get Token issued
$token = $con.access_token
#Add token to HashTable
$paramsHT.add('AccessToken',$token)
#Connect to GraphAPI
Connect-MgGraph @paramsHT
```

But by doing so you have to handle the token refresh by yourself.

Comment: The question is specifically about how to read from a PKCS12 file. To the best of my knowledge the PKCS12 format is the de-facto format for how to store a certificate and its private key as a bundle.

As for authenticating to MS Graph, Microsoft, in their documentation, specifically discourages password-based authentication. Certificate-based authentication is the way forward.

Comment: I showed you the possibilities which route you chose is up to you... Idk what you are missing, you can read all properties of the cert by accessing the variable $cert and you can use the variable to authenticate

Comment: As far as I can tell the .Net constructor `X509Certificate2([path],[password])` doesn't fit the bill of loading a standardized file into X509Certificate2 object _incl_ private key.  It cannot be used for that. The only standardized file type it can read is PKCS7 and that will not incl the private key.

Comment: ```$CERT.PrivateKey.key``` - I exported a cert from the win cert store inkl. private key protected by a password and can, by the mentioned method, access the information or use it to authenticate...

Comment: Again, there's no Windows here. Anyway, you were linking to the Core 3.1 docs for `X509Certificate2([path],[password])`. That document doesn't mention PKCS12. However, the document for .Net 6.0 does. Thanks. I'll test.